# react-d3-tree can't set node shape to local png

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

As titled. I have my nodeSvgShape defined as:

```
const nodeShape = {
      shape: 'image',
      shapeProps: {
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
          x: -20,
          y: -20,
          href:{tree_node},
      }
}
```

I made sure to import {tree_node} from the correct directory (changing that to a wrong directory makes React give a compilation error). However, the nodes look like the default image that would show up if the image failed to load.

I tried replacing that href with an online link (but different image) and it works:

```
const nodeShape = {
      shape: 'image',
      shapeProps: {
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
          x: -20,
          y: -20,
          href:"https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png",
      }
}
```

But again, that's not the image I actually want, therefore I still need to figure out why my local image failed to load. What could be the reason? Thanks